# MYSQL get data within an certain time frame

Tags: php, mysql, date, intervals, between

hey everyone,
having problem getting this MYSQL query correct

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_problem 
WHERE user_id = 1
AND problem_solved != -1 
AND problem_timestamp BETWEEN '20110212' AND DATE('20110212', INTERVAL 14 DAY) 
ORDER BY problem_id
```

the problem is 20110212 is dynamically generated by php, which is why i use the DATE/INTERVAL COMBO.

what i am trying to do is select entries within a 2 week time frame given that you know the start date of that two week cycle.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Why not just get PHP to reformat it and then query for

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_problem 
WHERE user_id = 1
AND problem_solved != -1 
problem_timestamp > '2011-01-24' AND problem_timestamp < DATE_ADD('2011-02-12', INTERVAL 14 DAY) 
ORDER BY problem_id
```

To convert the date in PHP from your current format to MYSQL's format, use

```
$date = date_create_from_format('Ymd', '20110212');
$mysqlDate = date_format($date, 'Y-m-d'); //2011-01-24
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Datediff.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_problem 
WHERE user_id = 1
AND problem_solved != -1 
AND DATEDIFF(problem_timestamp,'20110112') <= 14
ORDER BY problem_id
```